# What type of wire nuts are recommended for #6 and #8 wires for oven installation?

Tags: electrical, wiring

For an experienced diy-er trying to install a 40A oven/microwave combo (8/3 cable) and a 50A rated range (6/3 cable), what type of specific wire nuts can I use that I can easily pick up at Lowe’s? Hopefully one that is good for both, 2x#6 and 2x#8 wire. Any twisting tips on those, or a link to a video is also appreciated.

This seem to be the fit, but wanted to double check as far as nuts as well as install tips: [Wing Twist Wire Connectors](https://www.lowes.com/pd/IDEAL-WingTwist-10-Pack-Blue-Wire-Connectors/3128791)

Edit: does this look good?
[image]

Comment: Mine are blue as well, FWIW. As long as the wires can't arc (due to being loose), you're good

Comment: I made sure they tightened well and the specs said min 3x #12 and Max 2x #6. Looks like this covers me for both gauges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to join some #6 and #8 wires in a nut. Took a few minutes of looking, but I found a small 6-pack of nuts that said it would support up to two #6 wires. The only thing different about these is they're much larger than the ones you'd normally use. There's no real terminology to look for, but read the bags to find sizing.

There's nothing special about twisting I found. Both were stranded, but they easily wrapped around one another and the nut screwed on like any other wire nut.

Comment: Twist them HARD. Give them a pull test.